# Getting a response through Curl URL in PHP

Tags: php, curl, response

I am trying to perform some function based on the response I will get from Curl URL. Below is the code I have written. But the response coming is always empty. Due to which the control always goes into an else condition.

```
if(isset($_POST['verify_button'])){
    
    $curl = curl_init();

       curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
           CURLOPT_URL => "https://*******/v1/****/*********/".$_POST['********']."?MVNO=*******",
           CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
           CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
           CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
           CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
           CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
           CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
           CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
           CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
           "Authorization: Basic Z*******",
           "accept: application/json"
           ),
       ));

       $response = curl_exec($curl);

       curl_close($curl);
       
       $data = json_decode($response);
       

    if($data->resultCode == '0'){
 echo '<div class="mm_success_alert">Sucess</div>';

}
else{
echo '<div class="mm_danger_alert">Fail.</div>';
}
```

Comment: You mean that `$response` is `=== false` ? Did you tried [`curl_error()`](https://php.net/curl_error) ?

Comment: I tried capturing $response in the alert box and it seems to be empty.

Comment: I am trying this way . 
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'.curl_error($curl).'");</script>';

Comment: Check with `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` parameters.